# Configuring eclipse.ini on Mac OS

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, jvm

I am trying to configure the eclipse.ini file in order to execute Eclipse through a JVM 1.8 I have just installed on my Mac.

I have added these lines

```
-vm 
 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05/Contents/Home/bin/
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
```

But I get the error

"No Java Virtual Machine was found after searching the following locations: 
 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05/Contents/Home/bin/

Comment: Is there a typo in your question? .exe are applications for windows OS and they won't work in Mac OS... Or maybe that's the problem?

Comment: -vm and /Library... must also be on separate lines

Answer (score 2):

You need supply the full path name to the executable itself

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java

Answer (score 0):

If you can run

```
java -version
```

simply remove this lines

```
-vm 
 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05/Contents/Home/bin/
```

and you haven't care about this in the future, when you update java